# Unable to pass an ARRAY through CURL?

Tags: php, arrays, curl, arraylist, php-curl

```
$items[] = array("sku"=>"data","name"=>"data","amount"=>0,"qty"=>"0","id"=>"data","price"=>0,"url"=>"data");

$post = array(
'data' => 'data',
            'items' => $items);

$ch = curl_init('urltopost');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); //timeout in seconds
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
     header('Location: error');
     die();
}
```

If I post it to itself and do `var_dump($_POST["items"]);` I just get  `string(5) "Array"`  as the output.

I also attempted a foreach loop which outputted no data.

**Am I being stupid and something glaringly wrong is up with it?**

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` i think you will see the issue then

Comment: That gave me all the data I wanted, could you point out the issue to me though?

Comment: `$items[]` .. creates a new dimension so it ends up as `$items[0]` .. you could just use `$items=array()`. https://ideone.com/FUJwGd

Comment: @smith I changed it to $items = array(); it didn't make any difference sadly

Comment: items will still be an array under an array becuse of your $post array

Comment: If I do var_dump($_POST["items"][0]); it says A, and then 1 goes to R, and it just spells out array?

Comment: its still one deeper due to $post

Comment: @smith How do I solve this smith?

Comment: Use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)?

Comment: look at: https://ideone.com/FUJwGd

Comment: This is been posted to a website @smith And they cannot handle it like how you have done it

Comment: its not what i have done, that's your code, you dont seem to be looking at what you have actually done. do you want `$items[0]` to be just $itmes array?

Comment: I fixed it thanks to @t.m.adam giving me the brilliant idea to use http_build_query, thank you very much!

Comment: Setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $items);` should have worked too. From the docs `Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.`. In your case seems the problem is that you are wrapping $items with another array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$post = [];
foreach($items as $index=>$item){
    $new_key = "item[$index]";
    foreach($item as $k=>$v){
        $post[$new_key.'['. $k .']'] = $v;
    }

}
$post['data'] = 'data';
```

The post array format is `array('key'=>string, ....)`, it not allow array. If you want post array, the key format is `'key[index1][index2] ...'`. In server you will receive `$_POST['key']` as array.